# angular msal-auth without ms graph

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, msal.js

I use msal-auth to get a token from azure (only auth once). The following auth only validates against the token without any Azure auth. My problem is now that it seems to need  ms-graph to validate the token. But I want to avoid ms-graph because of policy-problems internal. How can I avoid graph with msal-auth. What do I need to set as a valid **protectedResouceMap** ? It seems the angular app still uses ms-graph in background, even if there is no reference in code.
Here is my code in **app.module.ts**:

```
// Initiate the MSAL library with the MSAL configuration object
    MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig),{
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
      }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([
         ['domain.com', ['all.scope',
          {
            httpMethod: "GET",
            scopes: ["read.scope"]
          },
          {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            scopes: ["info.scope"]
          }]]
      ])
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    LocalStorageService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    MsalRedirectComponent
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For acquiring the token using the Angular Interceptor:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http"; // Import 

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

import { MsalModule, MsalRedirectComponent, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular'; // Import MsalInterceptor
import { InteractionType, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_Here',
        authority: 'Enter_the_Cloud_Instance_Id_Here/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here',
        redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here',
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          **['Enter_the_Graph_Endpoint_Here/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]**
      ])
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There is reference to graph endpoint, there is no mention of acquiring the token without graph endpoint reference.

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code#acquire-a-token

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, one question before I test, Is it possible to set another azure ad-endpoint to 'enter_graph_endpoint_here' from the list below  to avoid ms-graph-problems ? just one which is not graph
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments